# User can create reports and "Save As" but cannot "Save"

Tags: reporting

One of my users can only save reports as a new report (Save As) but cannot save.

This means she is creating duplicates all the time. Which profile permission does she need to have to be able to save.

(SF Classic Org)

Comment: It might be an issue with the report folder permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable "manage public reports" on profile

Comment: But you are giving access to save reports on any folder.in our organisation we follow procedure restrict to creating unwanted reports in any folder as well as changing criteria.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to access levels on the shared folder. IF access level is 'View' then users can only 'Save As' existing reports.

IF access level is 'Edit' then users can edit and Save existing reports.